# Uploading Error with name of App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I already filled the all details for app through my iOS Developer account and submit the app for review to the app store but for some reasons i take my app back and delete all the details  for particular app from my developer account but now when i again trying to upload the app for review it shows the Name already exist because of my app is submit with the same name again how can i over come this problem i want to upload my app with the same name again.

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Have you tried contacting Apple? http://developer.apple.com/contact/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you deleted your app, so you can't reuse the App Name. 
From [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf):

> If you have created an app in iTunes Connect that you no longer need
>   to see or manage, you can delete it  from your iTunes Connect view.
>   **IMPORTANT**: Deleting your app will not allow you to reuse your SKU or
>   App Name in the same account again  and you will not be able to
>   restore your app once deleted.  If you have uploaded a binary or set
>   up this app for  the iAd Network, your Bundle ID will not be reusable
>   either.